# Can't update SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm creating a website in ASP.NET (in c#) with campaigns listed into a datalist (seperated from each other by using a `<div>` in the datalist so each campaign is listed into a block).

I can't update a specific column in the Campaigns table via c# because it can't find the scalar variable @camp_id (the ID of the campaign).

I'm using this command to update:

```
sqlCmd = "UPDATE Campagnes SET camp_status=2 WHERE camp_id=@camp_id";
```

Someone who knows how to make it possible to update 'camp_status' to 2 by using the 'camp_id' so only the 'camp_status' of that specific campaign (and not from others in the datalist) will be updated?

Edit: this is my whole code I'm using:

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    string sqlConn;
    string sqlCmd;

    sqlConn = @"Data Source=my-ip,1433;Initial Catalog=DbName;
    Integrated Security=False;user id=sa;password=password";
    sqlCmd= "UPDATE Campagnes SET camp_status=2 WHERE camp_id=@camp_id";

    conn.ConnectionString = sqlConn;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = sqlCmd;
    conn.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
```

So as you can see I'm not using parameters yet because I don't know how to add this and how it reads the value from the database.

The full code I'm using at the moment:

```
SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();

        string sqlConn2;
        string sqlCmd2;

        sqlConn2 = @"Data Source=my-ip,1433;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=False;user id=sa;password=password";
        sqlCmd2 = "select * from Campagnes";

        conn2.ConnectionString = sqlConn2;
        cmd2.Connection = conn2;
        cmd2.CommandText = sqlCmd2;
        conn2.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            id = dr.GetInt32(0);






            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            string sqlConn;
            string sqlCmd;


            sqlConn = @"Data Source=my-ip,1433;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=False;user id=sa;password=password";
            sqlCmd = "UPDATE Campagnes SET camp_status=1 WHERE camp_id=" + id;



            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@camp_id", id);

            conn.ConnectionString = sqlConn;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = sqlCmd;
            conn.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();
        }
```

Can't upload my image right here so here an external link to the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHG9a.png

As you can see in the image, all the seperated white blocks are one datalist, but seperated by a div that will be generated when a new campaign will be added. When we click the edit button in the bottom of the right, the camp_status needs to be set to 2 (so the admin knows that the campaign needs to be edited).

ASP Source:

```
    div id="popUpPanel">
                <p>Waarom vindt u dat deze campagne nog niet in orde is? Geef uw feedback hieronder in:</p>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="box" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click"  runat="server" Text="OK" />
            </div>

            <asp:DataList CellPading="5" ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" style="margin-right: 0px" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="list" style="padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="titelLabel" runat="server" style="font-size: xx-large" Text='<%# Eval("titel") %>' />
                    <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" style="font-size: xx-large; display: none;" Text='<%# Eval("camp_id") %>' />

                    <asp:Label ID="datum_geplaatstLabel"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("datum_geplaatst") %>' />
                    <br /><br />
                        <strong>Korte beschrijving:</strong><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="korte_beschrijvingLabel"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("korte_beschrijving") %>' />

                    <br /><br />
                        <strong>Lange beschrijving:</strong><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lange_beschrijvingLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("lange_beschrijving") %>' />
                    <br />
                        <table class="auto-style1">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="auto-style2"><strong>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/edit.png" OnClientClick="showPopUp(); return false;" Style="margin-left:9px;" />
                                    </strong></td>

                                <td><strong>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" asp:Imagebutt="" ImageUrl="~/img/vink.png" Style="margin-left:0px;" />
                                    </strong></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    <br />
                        </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WebhoostConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [titel], [datum_geplaatst], [korte_beschrijving], [lange_beschrijving], [camp_id] FROM [Campagnes]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

So when we click on the 'Button1' in the PopupPanel the camp_status needs to be set to 2 only of that specific campaign. As you can see in the source I was also trying to use the label I was talking about, but everytime a new div is created, all coming labels will have 'Label1' as ID so it will also pick all campaign ID's and not just one..
```

ASP source code (using the CommandArgument in the button):

```
<div id="popUpPanel">
            <p>Waarom vindt u dat deze campagne nog niet in orde is? Geef uw feedback hieronder in:</p>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="box" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" CommandArgument='<%= Campagnes.camp_id %>' />
        </div>



        <asp:DataList CellPading="5" ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" style="margin-right: 0px" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="list" style="padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">
                &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="titelLabel" runat="server" style="font-size: xx-large" Text='<%# Eval("titel") %>' />
                <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" style="font-size: xx-large; display: none;" Text='<%# Eval("camp_id") %>' />

                <asp:Label ID="datum_geplaatstLabel"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("datum_geplaatst") %>' />
                <br /><br />
                    <strong>Korte beschrijving:</strong><br />
                <asp:Label ID="korte_beschrijvingLabel"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("korte_beschrijving") %>' />

                <br /><br />
                    <strong>Lange beschrijving:</strong><br />
                <asp:Label ID="lange_beschrijvingLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("lange_beschrijving") %>' />
                <br />
                    <table class="auto-style1">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style2"><strong>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/edit.png" OnClientClick="showPopUp(); return false;" Style="margin-left:9px;" />
                                </strong></td>

                            <td><strong>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" asp:Imagebutt="" ImageUrl="~/img/vink.png" Style="margin-left:0px;" />
                                </strong></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                <br />
                    </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WebhoostConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [titel], [datum_geplaatst], [korte_beschrijving], [lange_beschrijving], [camp_id] FROM [Campagnes]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C# source code (edited EventArgs to CommandEventArgs e):

```
string id;

    SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();

    string sqlConn2;
    string sqlCmd2;

    sqlConn2 = @"Data Source=81.169.242.73,1433;Initial Catalog=Webhoost;Integrated Security=False;user id=sa;password=63310Kw1c";
    sqlCmd2 = "select * from Campagnes";

    conn2.ConnectionString = sqlConn2;
    cmd2.Connection = conn2;
    cmd2.CommandText = sqlCmd2;
    conn2.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
      id = e.CommandArgument.ToString();






            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        string sqlConn;
        string sqlCmd;


        sqlConn = @"Data Source=81.169.242.73,1433;Initial Catalog=Webhoost;Integrated Security=False;user id=sa;password=63310Kw1c";
        sqlCmd = "UPDATE Campagnes SET camp_status=1 WHERE camp_id=" + id;



        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@camp_id", id);

        conn.ConnectionString = sqlConn;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = sqlCmd;
        conn.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling your update statement? Can you post the whole code.

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: Have you added a parameter with that name to your command?

Comment: You need to post your c# update code to be sure, but you're probably missing setting your SqlParameter @camp_id or passing it to the command.

Comment: Did you execute the query using `sqlCmd.executeNonQuery();` ?

Comment: show your complete code . A peace of code is not anything wrong

Comment: Added the whole code!

Comment: There is no update statement in that code.

Comment: Your sqlCmd variable is set to "" (empty)... you're not assigning the update command to it

Comment: I was forgotten to add it. It is added now :)

Comment: where in your code do you extract the id of the record you want to update? This is normally all done with some kind of grid control

Answer (score 3):

You have to define and add the parameter @camp_id

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@camp_id", youCampIdValue);
```

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages now, thanks. However at 'youCampIdValue' needs to be a value that is read from the Databse, so in that case the current 'camp_id'. Do you understand what I mean or not haha?

Comment: hm so you have to first use a sql statement to retrieve the id :)

Comment: Yes I know, I did test it with a sqlDataReader and I know how to retrieve data from the database, but till now, it retrieves all rows.. So it will update the 'camp_status' from all campaigns, and that's not what I want. You know how to retrieve it only from the specific campaign?

Comment: To answer this, I would have to know the DB schema and data :-)
Your SQL Query should only get the specific campaign you want to update... only the single result

Comment: Hm okay, shall I upload the code I've used to create the tables etc? Shall I also upload a screenshot of the page I'm talking about to visualize my question a bit more?

Comment: Yes please and post the code you use to retrieve the camp_ids

Comment: Added a screenshot and the code to retrieve the id from the db

Comment: its pretty obvious why every campaign gets updated... with your `sqlcmd2` you're selecting `all` campaigns and with the while loop you're looping through all campaingns and get each id, thus updating every campaign... try to select only the one campaign which you want to update

Comment: Yes I already recognized that. But the problem is that I don't know how to select only that campaign. I cannot put just a random camp_id, no it needs to be exactly that id of that campaign I'm currently looking at. But I don't know how. I also tried it with labels that retrieves the ID from the campaign in the div, but that has the same effect as I'm doing now...

Comment: We'd need to see the asp-source to help you with that but I'm not sure if I can help you since I'm not an expert in ASP and this has not much to do with the original question :-) can you post the asp-source? BTW: why are you opening two connections and don't use just the one?

Comment: look basically you need to add the parameter to your button similarly to this: `<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" CommandArgument='<%= campaign.ID %>' OnCommand="Button1_Click" />` and in your Button1_Click method you can retrieve this parameter like this: `string id = e.CommandArgument.ToString();`

Comment: Done. But now I will get an error message when I click the button. It says 'Incorrect syntax near '<'' at  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: please edit your post to show the new code we can't help you with just the error message

Comment: @Kelvinvdh: you need to add the parameter to this query: `sqlCmd2 = "select * from Campagnes";` and i don't see the updated button in the asp code

Comment: Code has been added now. Don't know it wasn't visible. So you mean I need to add the parameter just like I did for cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(); But than for sqlcmd2?

Comment: sorry I can't help you anymore at this point. I think you need to get familiar with the basics of asp first. I suggest you read and to this tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/introduction-and-overview and especially for your problem the "Display data items and details" which will help you solve your problem